# Get detailed results from Facebook invite

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I would like to use FBSDKAppInviteDialog to have a user invite Facebook friends in exchange for in-app currency. The problem is that it returns a result of [didComplete: 1] which seems to be a binary pass/fail result rather than a count of how many friends were invited. Is there a way that I can log more detailed information like a list of names or at least a count of invites sent? Is there another method I should be using to achieve this?

Comment: You are not allowed to reward users for sending invites

Comment: You are only allowed to reward _successful_ invites. And in that case, you get the necessary data when the invited user joins your app.

Comment: Is there a resource that will show me how to track that information?